# How to enable OpenVPN client to address remote computers using hostnames (using PfSense)?

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, hostname

How to allow OpenVPN clients to address remote computers using hostnames?

I VPN into a remote site using an OpenVPN server running on PfSense at the remote site.

The remote PfSense is running DNS and all computers on that network can communicate with each other using hostnames.

When connected via VPN however, the remote computers are only accessible by their IP addresses and not their hostnames.

I've added `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.66.0.4"` to `VPN / OpenVPN / Servers / Edit / Advanced Configuration / Custom options` which was not successful.

There is a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/609572) however the PfSense server in that question was not the DHCP/DNS server whereas in my question it is both the DHCP and DNS server.

The [most similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/117836/) is from 2010 for OpenVPN only with no mention of PfSense.

How to enable OpenVPN clients to address remote computers using hostnames?

Comment: Are you using only a host name or a FQDN?

Comment: I am using hostnames only

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the DNS server option, you also need to push a default DNS search domain so your VPN clients.

Comment: Would I do this using the DNS forwarder? Which settings should be applied?